# Installing cuda 10.1 but getting 10.2

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have uninstalled all my cuda versions, and still when I type nvidia-smi in the commandline I get this which shows 10.2
How can that be?

[image]

Here's anaconda navigator saying 10.1 is installed currently

[image]

Comment: In the output of nvidia-smi, "CUDA version" refers to the *maximum* CUDA version supported by the currently installed *driver*. It does not tell you anything about the CUDA version currently installed.

Comment: @njuffa I see, this make sense. It's really confusing.

Comment: Given that I have explained this to more than a dozen confused people so far, I agree. NVIDIA should think up a better way of communicating this information.